# Не работает конструктор формы Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

Установлена Visual Studio 2015.
Создаю **CLR** - **Пустой проект CLR**
Далее в свойствах выставляю сразу подсистему - **Windows**, и точку входа - **Main**.
После этого **Добавить** - **Создать элемент** - **UI** - **Windows Form**. Появляются два файла, заголовочный и cpp.
Сразу же при создании появляется ошибка конструктора
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ладно, закрываю. Кидаю код в **MyForm.cpp**:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int Main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    project9::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);

    return 0;
}
```

Сохраняю. Запускаю проект, форма появляется.

Опять хочу открыть **MyForm.h** через конструктор, получаю в ответ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окей. Открываю **MyForm.h** просто через редактор, открыло код. Хорошо. 
Жмякаю опять открыть через конструктор, получаю в ответ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что происходит с этой студией... Как это исправить?
Я просто хотел открыть форму в конструкторе

Comment: Это не студия, а это больше проблема конфигурации CRL Windows Forms. Я точно не помню, вам нужно нажать на стек вызовов и дальше смотреть ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Надо в `MyForm.h` добавить там где остальные такие же

```
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
```

и щёлкните обратно на конструктор и уже он будет без ошибки, а как надо.

Ещё видел возникает вопрос у народа, что не открывается конструктор по двойному щелчку - сохранить проект, закрыть студию и открыть снова и заработает.